# Error: Invalid task definition: Could not find container definition with matching name

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, github-actions, amazon-ecs, aws-devops

I'm getting below error, how can I resolve this issue

Error: Invalid task definition: Could not find container definition with matching name

below I have added in my task definition

```
 "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8000
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": 500,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/app-server-repo:c63619a84827c463f7d3c5a78da6280f9ea3efec",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "app-server-con"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: So you have a container definition named `"app-server-con"`. You need to refer to that in your task definition somewhere, and apparently you are using another name, but you haven't shown your entire task definition, just the container definition, so there isn't enough here for anyone to help you.